# opengl texturing

Tags: opengl

I am trying to create a normal map in opengl that I can load into the shader and change dynamically, though currently i am stuck at how to create the texture.

I currently have this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE7);
glGenTextures(1, &normals);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, normals);
texels = new Vector3f*[256];

for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){
    texels[i] = new Vector3f[256];
}
this->setup_normals();

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, texels);
```

...

```
void setup_normals(){
for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 256; ++j){
            texels[i][j][0] = 0.0f;
            texels[i][j][1] = 1.0f;
            texels[i][j][2] = 0.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

where Vector3f is:   typedef float Vector3f[3];

and texels is:  Vector3f** texels;

When I draw this texture to a screenquad using an orthogonal matrix( which works for textures loaded in) I get [image: this].

I am unsure why it does not appear fully green and also what is causing the black streaks to appear within it.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array needs to be contiguous since `glTexImage2D()` doesn't take any sort of stride or row mapping parameters:

```
texels = new Vector3f[256*256];
```

Comment: That did it thank you, just out of interest do you know if there is any way to use multi dimensional arrays?  maybe by changing some parameters  using glPixelstoref?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not the way you were creating your array.  `new` can return pretty much any memory address with no spec-mandated relationship to prior allocations.

Comment: @Bunnit: C and C++ dynamic "multidimensional" arrays are not what you may think they are. Only the last dereferenciation in a chain of index operators actually points to data. All the preceding index operators dereference into arrays of more pointers.